# how to get Network Compter Name and Netwok IP "Not internet IP" in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ip

as i'm going to create Maintenance Request Page, so any employee can use this page from our local Network without internet, and i want to get the computer name and Ip for the one which made the request,

i search and read about this, but most if what i got it is: how to get the internet ip or host name and IP but my question is "how to get Network Compter Name and Netwok IP "Not internet IP" in Asp.Net"??

some of what i found it about Internet Ip and Host Info is:

```
using System.Net;
//Get the Host name:

    string strHostName = string.Empty;
    strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();

    // Then using host name, get the IP address list..
    IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostByName(strHostName);
    //Get the IP address
    IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;
    for (int i = 0; i < addr.Length; i++)
    {
        Response.Write("IP Address {0}: {1} " + i + addr[i].ToString() + ", HostName: " + strHostName);
    } 
    // end of host info.
```

and this way for internet info:

```
Response.Write("Your IP Address: " + Request.UserHostAddress + "<BR>");
Response.Write("Your Computer Name: " + System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.UserHostAddress).HostName);
```

so is there any way to get the local Ip and Name of computer??

Comment: what do you mean by "local IP" and "network computer name"? The code you put is correct: you want `Dns.GetHostName()`. Remember that NetBIOS names are irrelevant today, and 127.0.0.1 is always the "local" IP address. Is your machine multi-homed or operating simultaneously on the Internet and a private network?

Comment: what i mean is: our employee will use this page as internal network, and as u know there is internal ip for each computer not public internet ip , and each computer in our network have name refer to department so i want to get the internal ip and computer name to use it in maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have DNS correctly configured to be updated with the names of computers as they connect and disconnect, then you can use reverse resolution to get from the client IP address back to the host name.

If your web site is inside the firewall, the connected user host address will be the internal address and can be resolved. If the site is hosted outside (or possibly in the DMZ) then you will not be able to get the name without requiring the user to provide it - or by running some trusted code on the client to access the local information.